# Click anywhere on touch device (iPad/iPhone) to hide dropdown that is toggled by .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a dropdown menu that is displayed when the user hovers over a nav link. This is being triggered in jQuery with .hover(). The opening and closing of this dropdown works fine on touch devices when the user clicks the nav link (iPad/iPhone), but I am trying to hide the dropdown when the user clicks anywhere else on the page.

[Here is a link to my JSFiddle with a basic setup.](https://jsfiddle.net/bluebomber/rdfjh8ok/)

I have found ways of doing this with .click(), but not .hover().

This is my basic jQuery code:

```
$('.hoverItem').hover(function(e) {
  $('.dropdown').toggleClass('visible');
  e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the body clickable, and hide the dropdown when it is clicked like this?

HTML:

```
<body id="clickArea">
<div class="hoverItem">Hover here to show dropdown</div>
<div class="dropdown">Dropdown Area</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('.hoverItem').hover(function(e) {
$('.dropdown').toggleClass('visible');
});

$('#clickArea').click(function(e) {
$('.dropdown').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/howzdh5a/)

Answer (score 0):

First, it is far better, imho, to use:

```
.on(click, function(e))
```

vs

```
.hover(function(e))
```

Next, would be an if / else statement.

```
var navcheck = $(this).attr(class);
if(navcheck!=dropdown){ $(.dropdown).hide(); } else { $(dropdown).show(); }
```

Comment: Does .on(click, function(e)) still act like a hover or will it be a click. I really need to dropdown to only show when I hover

Comment: You can apply any action preference: .on(hover, mouseover, touchstart, click, etc)